# Reorder array depending on children

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get an ordered array to be able to execute children first then all parent.

Here is an example:

```
var p1=[c1,c2,c3] // c1,c2,c3 are children
var p2=[c4,c5,c6]
var c1=[c2,p2] // but c1 can depend on parent
```

So the result should be :

```
var result=[c2,c6,c4,c5,c2,c3,p2,c1,p1]
```

Another example could be to reorder npm dependencies to install all children first then remaining parents to avoid error because of missing child install.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look at sorting: [Array.prototype.sort() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Here's a straightforward implementation of the Kahn's algorithm (see the link):

```js
var graph = {
    p1: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
    p2: ['c4', 'c5', 'c6'],
    c1: ['c2', 'p2']
};

var terminals = {},
    sorted = [];

Object.keys(graph).forEach(n =>
    graph[n].forEach(k =>
        k in graph ? '' : terminals[k] = 1));

terminals = Object.keys(terminals);

while (terminals.length !== 0) {
    var t = terminals.shift();
    sorted.push(t);
    Object.keys(graph).forEach(n => {
        graph[n] = graph[n].filter(x => x != t);
        if (graph[n].length === 0) {
            terminals.push(n);
            delete graph[n];
        }
    });
}

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: neat, so basically the first children have no special order, because they are independent.

Comment: Seems to be the concept, but when trying with ```var graph = {
    p1: ['c1', 'p2', 'c3'],
    p2: ['c4', 'c5', 'c6'],
    c1: ['p1', 'p2']
};```, then c1 and p1 are missing. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Alphapage: there's a circular dependency here : `p1 -> c1 -> p1`. You cannot topologically sort a cycled graph.